# Google Maps API - Infowindow Content from mySQL database and displayed via ClusterMarkerer

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

This is probably a ridiculously simple question.

I am trying to show a map, where marker infowindow will show the following content:

Name
Address
 
About (ie, description)
 
URL

Markers are queried from a mySQL database using PHP. The code is currently mapping all markers correctly, but only shows the "name" attribute in the infowindow. What is the missing code necessary to add the 3 other attributes? (Address, About, URL?) My guess is that there's something at this point in the code that needs adjustment:

```
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
```

If possible, please answer with the necessary script!

-Live link to database output: http://www.oaktonjapan.com/testmap/testcode3.php
***Note that the 1st (PAX Coworking) and last (Venture Generation) are populated with "address, about, and URL content.

-Live link to existing output: http://oaktonjapan.com/testmap/testmap5.html

***Click on the red sumo wrestler marker. This marker should show all 4 attributes if coded correctly...

Current Code:

```
 function load() {
  var cluster = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.681382,139.766084),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var min = .999999;
    var max = 1.000001;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("testcode3.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var about = markers[i].getAttribute("about");
      var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
      var offsetLat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      var offsetLng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(offsetLat, offsetLng);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        content: html
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));   
      cluster.push(marker);
    }
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);
  });
}


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Comments are not designed for extensive detail, the best thing to do would be to edit your question to add the things you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried to do the following with no avail: -Altering the infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name")), altering the marker definition (ie, var marker = ) I've searched Google Maps API, which helped substantially, but I have yet to find a tutorial which incorporates mySQL and MarkerClusterer. The closest tutorial was https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=en#createmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought you would be getting a variable not defined error on "html".

This is where you get the data out of the xml:

```
  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
  var about = markers[i].getAttribute("about");
```

This would combine it into the list you specified above:

```
  var html = name + "<br>" + address + "<br>"+ about + "<br>" + url;
```

This would display it in the infowindow (don't know why you have the "content: html" there, but at least now it won't cause an error):

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    content: html
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(html);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
```